# Swift - Nil when using 'as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Swift noobie here trying to follow the tutorial seen [here](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/building-a-custom-sticker-pack-imessage-application-for-ios-10-368285c9a2c) to build a custom sticker application. I am able to compile the application to a simulator but not to my phone.

The initial code is as follows:

```
class FoodDrawerCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
let numberOfItemsPerRow = 3.0 as CGFloat
let interItemSpacing = 1.0 as CGFloat
let interRowSpacing = 1.0 as CGFloat
let sectionTitleKey = "SectionTitle"
let sectionItemsKey = "Items"
var data = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80, left: 0, bottom: 40, right: 0)
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FoodDrawerData", ofType: ".plist") {
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let allSections = dict["Sections"]
        if let selectedSections = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedSections") as? [Int] {
            for index in selectedSections {
                    self.data.append((allSections![index.description]) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line causing me issue is

```
 self.data.append((allSections![index.description]) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
```

I am not sure how to revise the code to prevent the unwrapping of the optional value as I am not seeing direct examples that help me recode this portion of the code. Could anyone please advise and explain what is going on with my variables and whether it is `index.description`, `data`, `selectedSections`, or something else causing the problem?

Thank you guys!

Comment: try using [String : AnyObject]

Comment: That is a pretty poor tutorial.  It uses , instead of : and lots of force unwrapping

Comment: Indeed. Stay away from `!` as much  as you can, and always check your optionals contain a value with `if let`, `guard let`, `as?` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

```
    // use as? instead of as!
    // it might return nil
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    if let dict = dict {
        // the following might be nil
        if let allSections = dict["Sections"] {
            // Sections was found
        }
        else {
            // Sections not found
        }
    }
    else {
        // dict is nil
    }
```

Comment: Optional bindings for data retrieved from the application bundle is nonsense. **You** created the file, it can't be `nil` and **you know** the type of its contents.

Comment: Exactly. If it _is_ nil then you want a crash and fix the file, not handle the error.

Comment: That is your opinion. Handle it in your code however you wish. I would rather handle any exception scenario gracefully.

Comment: That's not an opinion, that's a fact. There is more than black and white when handling optionals. And there is a significant difference between a design (time) error – which is controllable – and a runtime error – which is not.